# Enviando una imagen por WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Quiero enviar una imagen por whatsapp a un numero telefónico determinado sin necesidad de ingresar a la galería de imágenes y dentro del chat del contacto.

ahora lo que hago es lo siguiente:

```
    Intent intent = new intent();
    intent.setaction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    intent.setData(Uri.Parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+333333"))
    intent.setType("image/*");

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("/storange/emulate/0/imagen.png"));

    startActivity(intent);
```

con este código logro casi todo. Se carga la imagen pero me deja fuera del chat. Tengo que elegir al usuario. No lee el intent.Setdata y no ingresa al chat del contacto. (o sea que me deja fuera del chat y yo necesito que ingrese para solo apretar el botón enviar y listo). Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: de donde obtuviste este código? no podría compilar, hay métodos que no existen como ".setaction()", el folder es "storage" no "storange".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El código que muestras no podría compilar, ya que tiene varios errores.
En lugar de usar el path "`/storange/emulate/0/`", usa `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` con el cual obtendrás el path del directorio externo.

Te sugiero este método

```
 private void sendImageWhatsApp(String phoneNumber, String nombreImagen) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + nombreImagen));
        intent.putExtra("jid", phoneNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //numero telefonico sin prefijo "+"!
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(intent);
     } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no esta instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

El método recibe el número telefónico que tengas registrado, sin el prefijo "+" (esto es muy importante) y el nombre de la imagen.

Ejemplo:

```
 sendImageWhatsApp("333333", "imagen.png");
```

**Por cuestiones de seguridad, la API de WhatsApp no permite enviar automáticamente el mensaje**, únicamente lo muestra y estaría listo para que el usuario agregué más información o interactué dando clic en el botón "enviar":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, como se haría esto para una aplicación web, con JavaScript por ejemplo o PHP ? Gracias