# Adjunto en whatsapp por java

Tags: java, android, whatsapp, mensajes

Necesito enviar un archivo adjunto por medio de la app de whatsapp hasta ahora lo que e realizado es

```
    public void whatsapp(String phone){
    String mobile = phone.replace(" ", "+");

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + mobile);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Pero este metodo solo me sirve para enviar texto, existe algun otro metodo en el cual pueda seleccionar un archivo?

Comment: Lee la API mi estimado, ahí viene un ejemplo con curl, ¿Te funciona con curl?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/media

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estas realizando ùnicamente envía mensaje a un nùmero tèlefonico definido.

Si deseas enviar un archivo anexo, es importante que el archivo se encuentre descargado en disco.

Puedes ver este ejemplo de como se realiza el envió de una imágen.

[Enviando una imagen por WhatsApp](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79996/enviando-una-imagen-por-whatsapp)

Modifica el método para enviar un archivo

```
private void sendImageWhatsApp(String numTelefono, String nombreArchivo) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + nombreArchivo));
        intent.putExtra("jid", numTelefono + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //numero telefonico sin prefijo "+"!
        intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(intent);
     } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no se encuentra instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que tendrías que especificar el tipo de archivo que desees mandar, en el siguiente ejemplo es si deseas mandar un PDF:

```
public void whatsapp(String ruta){


File outputFile = new File(ruta + "example.pdf");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);

Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("application/pdf");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

activity.startActivity(share); 

}
```

Puedes revisar en la documentación los tipos de archivos que puedes mandar mediante el intent y agregar en el parámetro `setType("tipo de archivo")`