# Como puedo enviar archivos de texto a whatsapp desde mi app en android studio

Tags: android-studio

Cordial saludo para todos...
Estoy tratando de enviar un archivo de texto a un contacto de whatsapp...
Yo hice la prueba de enviar un mensaje y tuve exito con este codigo

```
Intent y = new Intent();
y.setPackage ("com.whatsapp");
y.setAction (Intent_ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Este es mi mensaje, por Ahora.....");
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(y);
```

Pero no he podido hallar la forma correcta de enviar un archivo de texto que se genera desde mi app.
Agradezco mucho si alguien me puede orientar al respecto.

De antemano Gracias por el apoyo...

Ya hice el ajuste al codigo. Me ha quedado asi:

```
    btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "archivo.pdf");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no se encuentra instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

Pero al momento de ejecutarlo se detiene cuando va realizar la acción startActivity(intent) En el móvil me  aparece un mensaje que dice que la app se detuvo y se cancela. Que debo corregir o agregar a mi codigo...?

En el Logcat me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Process: com.example.enviarmensajewhatsapp, PID: 13384
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/archivo.pdf exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
    at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1960)
    at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356)
    at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:942)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10039)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10045)
    at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:10024)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1610)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4585)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4543)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4904)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4872)
    at com.example.enviarmensajewhatsapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6367)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25040)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:795)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:450)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: Intentaste creando el `intent` de tipo `ACTION_SENDTO`?

Comment: Para realizar esto necesitas saber exactamente donde esta el archivo, y el archivo esta descargado. Puedes obtener la ruta donde se descarga el archivo? Cual es el código que genera el archivo de texto? . Revisa este ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79996/enviando-una-imagen-por-whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo adjunto un PDF ubicado en la carpeta de descargas.

Básicamente utilizo el mismo intent, pero en lugar de texto, le paso un stream con el archivo a adjuntar

```
File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "ejemplo.pdf"); 
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("application/pdf");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
activity.startActivity(share);
```

Si no mal recuerdo, debes tener el archivo en una carpeta de acceso público o whatsapp no podrá verlo, pero no tengo forma de comprobarlo ahora.

Comment: Ya hice la prueba pero cuando va a realizar el startActivity() se detiene la app. Yo trate de hacerlo como como esta en tu ejemplo: activity.startActivity() pero pero me dice que no puede resolver activity, no lo reconoce y si se lo quito la app se detiene, no ejecuta la  actividad.... Que puede ser....?

Comment: ¿Has revisado el log, para ver la razón por la que se detuvo la aplicación?

Comment: Muchas gracias.. Lo voy a probar...